# Code on generating possible ordered pairs up to a number and finding maximum value of binary operations of the pairs

Tags: c

I got a question at hackerrank which states that a user should input a larger  number (say 5) and a smaller number (say 4). Then. taking each pair from the ordered list {1,2,3,4,5}, the binary AND (`&`), binary OR (`|`), and binary X-OR (`^`) are performed. Here, 10 such values of each binary operation are found. The maximum value among the 10 values for a particular operation which is less than 4 is to be printed. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
int n,k,i,a,b;
printf("ENTER VALUE OF n AND k:");
scanf("%d%d",&n,&k);
int Aarr[n*(n-1)/2] , Oarr[n*(n-1)/2], Xarr[n*(n-1)/2];
for(a=1;a<=n;a++){
  for(b=a+1;b<n;b++){
     for(i=0;i<(n*(n-1)/2);i++){
         Aarr[i]=(a&b);
     }
     for(i=0;i<(n*(n-1)/2);i++){
         Oarr[i]=(a|b);
     }
     for(i=0;i<(n*(n-1)/2);i++){
         Xarr[i]=(a^b);
     }
  }
}
int Amax=1,Omax=1,Xmax=1;
for(i=0;i<(n*(n-1)/2);i++){
   if((Aarr[i]>Amax)&&(Aarr[i]<k)){
      Amax=Aarr[i];
   }
}
for(i=0;i<(n*(n-1)/2);i++){
   if((Oarr[i]>Omax)&&(Oarr[i]<k)){
      Omax=Oarr[i];
   }
}
for(i=0;i<(n*(n-1)/2);i++){
   if((Xarr[i]>Xmax)&&(Xarr[i]<k)){
      Xmax=Xarr[i];
   }
}
printf("\n%d\n%d\n%d",Amax,Omax,Xmax);
getchar();
```

}

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
2
2
3
```

**MY OUTPUT:**

```
1
1
1
```

My code is run in the **CODE BLOCKS** IDE. The code just produces the values of `Amax`, `Omax`, and `Xmax` as defined. I at first tried to find all the possible ordered pairs and store them in an array. I think the condition applied to find the maximum value of a particular operation is correct. I've done many debuggings and at last have sought your help. I'm new to C programming. So, my code seem to be too long to you.

**MY EDIT:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
int n,k,i=0,a,b;
printf("ENTER VALUE OF n AND k:");
scanf("%d%d",&n,&k);
int Aarr[n*(n-1)/2] , Oarr[n*(n-1)/2], Xarr[n*(n-1)/2];
for(a=1;a<=n;a++){
  for(b=a+1;b<n;b++){

     Aarr[i]=a&b;
     printf("%d\n",Aarr[i]);


     Oarr[i]=a|b;
     printf("%d\n",Oarr[i]);

     Xarr[i]=a^b;
     printf("%d\n",Xarr[i]);

     i++;
      }
     printf("\n");
    }
int Amax=1,Omax=1,Xmax=1;
    for(i=0;i<(n*(n-1)/2);i++){
   if((Aarr[i]>Amax)&&(Aarr[i]<k)){
      Amax=Aarr[i];
   }
 }
     for(i=0;i<(n*(n-1)/2);i++){
   if((Oarr[i]>Omax)&&(Oarr[i]<k)){
      Omax=Oarr[i];
   }
  }
for(i=0;i<(n*(n-1)/2);i++){
   if((Xarr[i]>Xmax)&&(Xarr[i]<k)){
      Xmax=Xarr[i];
   }
 }
printf("\n%d\n%d\n%d",Amax,Omax,Xmax);
getchar();
 }
```

The above revised code works. I hope it's ok.

Comment: Downvoted for sloppy typos.

Comment: @TomZych ... Where should I improve my typos ?I tried to explain my problem and my code too . What more should I do ?

Comment: Just proofread carefully. You’ve demonstrated that you know how to spell “binary” and “ordered”, so a lot of this is just carelessness.

Comment: It’s also a good idea to link to the original problem, so people can refer to it for clarification.

Comment: your punctuation is off.  commas and periods only need a space ***after*** them

Comment: You might consider adding some comments to your example to show what the intent of each section is. It might also help you figure out where you've gone wrong when you try to explain what the code does and you have an 'aha!' moment.

Comment: Hint: print the values in each of your arrays after they've been filled.

Comment: Looks like it’s this one? https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bitwise-operators-in-c/problem

Comment: @dbush .. thanks for the suggestion ..I'll try doing it...

Comment: @TomZych ..yes it is ...

Comment: I feel like you made this really complicated but it doesn't need to be. This passed the tests. https://ideone.com/Id7Vl1

Comment: @RetiredNinja ... That's more simplified ... I just dragged it too long ....thanks

Comment: If they gave awards for going off into the weeds on some of their questions I'd have more than one. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple of problems:

```
for(a=1;a<=n;a++){
  for(b=a+1;b<n;b++){
     for(i=0;i<(n*(n-1)/2);i++){
         Aarr[i]=(a&b);
     }
     ...
```

This code is storing the same value in every element of the `Aarr` array, because the values of `a` and `b` do not change as `i` changes. You need to store a different value in each element. Looking at it another way, you need to store each value in a different element.

The good news is that you just need the result of very combination of `a` and `b`. Since all you're interested in is the maximum value, you don't need to save them all.

```
for(a=1;a<n;a++){
  for(b=a+1;b<=n;b++){
     result_and = a&b;
     if(max_and < result_and)
         max_and = result_and;
     }
     result_or = a|b;
     if(max_or < result_or)
     ...
```

Note that I've also revised the logic on the `for` loops, because the conditions were the wrong way around. If `n` is `3`, for example, you want to do the following tests: 1 and 2, 1 and 3, 2 and 3. So the first `for` should *not* execute if a==n, but the second `for` *should*.

Another point. Don't forget to initialize the variables `max_and` *etc.* to a number that's going to be smaller than any test result.

Comment: I understood everything,except *If n is 3, then, the assignment to Aarr will only be done for a==1.* .... And I've put my own review in the question .Please check .

Comment: Yes, I was going to write an answer using `i++` after doing all the checks. But then I realized that you don't need to store the values, just accumulate the maximum